# AWS SWF - change default 60 seconds while Polling for Decision Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf, poller

As stated in AWS SWF [PollForDecisionTask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_PollForDecisionTask.html) docs, Amazon SWF holds the connection open for up to 60 seconds, and returns a task as soon as it becomes available.

My problem is that I have a cron that runs the poller every one minute, so on each iteration I don't wont it to be running 60 seconds. Is there any way in which I could change that default value? (I'm using AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js).

Comment: Did you check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/setting-timeouts.html#setting-timeouts-limits

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I am looking for... Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change this value. I would recommend switching from CRON to a persistently running process that executes poll in a loop.